# Function inside onclick event handler is not executed when the element is added dynamically

Tags: jquery, ajax, spinner

I had difficulties using `gif` images with `IE` and then I found out [spinner js](http://fgnass.github.io/spin.js/) which made my life a lot easier in this regard. However I have one problem. I'm reloading a table with data using `Ajax` calls. Each row has a dynamically added `<button>` hodling an `Id` and `onclick` event :

```
<button value= row[0] onClick="showDetailedInfo(this);return false;">Details</button>
```

the problem is that the spinner is working fine unless I call it from the `showDetailedInfo(this)` function. Then I don't get the spinner at all and the actual execution takes time because I make a lot of Server side work before sending back details (again with Ajax). Since I'm using the spinner on a lot of places I can't think of any other reason other than the fact that the function that is calling the spinner is handling event on a dynamically added element (But the function itself is loaded along with the other javascript).

For those that are not familiar with `spinner js` I'm calling it like this:

```
var opts = {
  lines: 13, // The number of lines to draw
  length: 20, // The length of each line
  ... more options
  }

var target = document.getElementById('foo');
var spinner = new Spinner(opts).spin(target);
```

However while I was searching for possible solution I read that initializing the options like this may cause this problem I switched to the `jQuery` plugin and now I call the spinner simply like this:

```
$('#foo').spin()
```

but no change in the behaviour. Still not sure if the `opts` part is not making some problems. Now I'm not using custom options and I let the spinner to use it's default options so I think it should not be a problem, but anyways. Ideas why this happen and how to make my spinner work?

Comment: Can you provide code of `showDetailedInfo` function and function, which adds `button`s? Moreover, `onclick=""` is outdated way to handle events.

Comment: @Regent it turned out that because in the `$.ajax` call the option `async` was set to `false` I was getting this behaviour. So indeed it wasn't because I render the button dynamically as I first thouth. Even though I wonder why I get this behaviour when I call `$('#foo').spin()` right before the `$.ajax` call. The function itself is pretty long because I collect a lot of data but in essence it's calling the spinner and the triggering ajax call the other is just collecting fields data.

Comment: Well, now you know why `async: false` is very bad and deprecated thing, don't you? :)

Comment: @Regent I didn't knew it was deprecated. Still `Ajax` is maybe the easiest way to send/recieve data from the server and also there are situations when you have to use it in `synch` mode. Not that there's not a programming solution but at the end the business demands take over the good programming logic. However thanks for sharing some of your time for my problem!

Comment: From [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/): _As of jQuery 1.8, the use of async: false with jqXHR ($.Deferred) is deprecated; you must use the success/error/complete callback options instead of the corresponding methods of the jqXHR object_

Comment: About _there are situations when you have to use it in synch mode_: these situations are incorrect code organizing, not a "have to" situation. You can always use callback function or `$.Deferred` `promise` to handle these situations. Really. Hanging browser process for several seconds is not a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is outdated. You can handle live events through jquery separate files, and for accessing elements added "on the fly" you have to use `$(document).on('click', 'button')`;

Your code should be like

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  $(document).on('click', 'button', function( e ){
    e.preventDefault();
    showDetailedInfo( this );
  });
});
```

It may need some small modifies ( it looks for all `button` inside page, and i don't know what exactly `showDetailedInfo` does )

Comment: I agree with you. The only problem that i couldn't solve and made me use `onclick` was that I wasn't able to detect the exact button that triggered the event and thus getting it's value since the value is the `id` which I use for.. mostly for everything. But I'm aware of the fact so given your code if I have 10 rows so 10 buttons when the event is triggered how can I take the `Value` value of the button which actually triggred it. As you can see in my code I pass a property `row[0]` which is `eval()`ed to actual Id number. How can I get this id using this approach?

Comment: @Leron `this` is passed to `showDetailedInfo` function in this answer, so you can use it just like in original code. `this` points to element, for which event handler was triggered.

Comment: hmm, gonna give it a try. Thanks a lot for the heads up.